# Redis on windows 11 says connection refused if we try to connect from a different machine

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, windows-11

I would like to inform that for windows 11 Redis installation on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS its observed that if we start Redis server and try to connect from a different system using redis-cli -h IP_Address -p 6379 its always says "Connection refused". Please let me know if we do have any solution for the above mentioned issue.

redis-cli -h IP_Address -p 6379

using this command from a remote machine.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, be sure to provide the server's IP address or hostname in the `-h` parameter to `redis-cli` when connecting.

if you're using a `redis.conf` file with your server, you'll need to enable connections from other hosts.  Add/change the `bind` directive as follows in your `redis.conf` file:

```
bind * -::*
```

By default, only connections from localhost are allowed.  Consider setting a password for your Redis instance using the `requirepass` directive if you're exposing the server outside of your local network.

Ref: https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/8e73f9d34821a937165884f13a2981883f44a074/redis.conf#L57